# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed SQL/java

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1055

I'm not the best with SQL, I purchased this script for voting. It worked like a charm until last night, where it started throwing Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed at me. The programmer said it looks fine and he is also confused by this error.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7077)
at com.mysql.jdbc.UpdatableResultSet.next(UpdatableResultSet.java:1118)
at mysql.impl.FoxVote.run(FoxVote.java:43)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the Java Class:

```
public class FoxVote implements Runnable {


public static final String HOST = "misthalinpk.com";
public static final String USER = "deleted";
public static final String PASS = "deleted";
public static final String DATABASE = "deleted";

private Player player;
private Connection conn;
private Statement stmt;
private int votes;

public FoxVote(Player player) {
    this.player = player;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if (!connect(HOST, DATABASE, USER, PASS)) {
            return;
        }

        String name = player.getUsername().replace(" ", "_");
        ResultSet rs = executeQuery("SELECT * FROM fx_votes WHERE username='"+name+"' AND claimed=0 AND callback_date IS NOT NULL");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String timestamp = rs.getTimestamp("callback_date").toString();
            String ipAddress = rs.getString("ip_address");
            int siteId = rs.getInt("site_id");


             if (player != null && player.getSession().getState() == SessionState.LOGGED_IN) {
                    player.getInventory().add(995, 100000);
                    player.getInventory().add(10944, 1);
                    votes++;
                    Achievements.finishAchievement(player, AchievementData.VOTE_FOR_US);
                    Achievements.doProgress(player, AchievementData.VOTE_100_TIMES);
                    if (++votes >= 15) {
                        World.sendMessage("[@red@Voting@bla@]@blu@Another 20 votes have been rewarded thanks to "+player.getUsername()+"!");
                        votes = 0;

            System.out.println("[Voting] Vote claimed by "+name+". (sid: "+siteId+", ip: "+ipAddress+", time: "+timestamp+")");

            rs.updateInt("claimed", 1); // do not delete otherwise they can reclaim!
            rs.updateRow();
        }

        destroy();
    }}} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public boolean connect(String host, String database, String user, String pass) {
    try {
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+":3306/"+database, user, pass);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Failing connecting to database!");
        return false;
    }
}

public void destroy() {
    try {
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
        if (stmt != null) {
            stmt.close();
            stmt = null;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int executeUpdate(String query) {
    try {
        this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement(1005, 1008);
        int results = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        return results;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}

public ResultSet executeQuery(String query) {
    try {
        this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement(1005, 1008);
        ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        return results;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Additionally, it should give 8 votes (maximum) at a time, but it only gives 1 before throwing the error.

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Ouch. This code appears to be susceptible to [sql injection](https://xkcd.com/327/). Also, the order of `stmt.close()` and `conn.close()` is reversed.

Comment: afaik the close operaitons should be  in following way : rs / stmt / conn

Comment: _"I purchased this script"_ -- double ouch! I hope that (a) you didn't pay much, and (b) you're not using it for anything mission-critical where failure or fraud would be expensive.